# Selectivity of metal nitrates towards ammonium bicarbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

I am performing coprecipitation reaction, and in the precipitating step, I have a bunch of metal nitrates(ferric nitrate, aluminium nitrate and barium nitrate)in a  solution reacting with ammonium bicarbonate.

I need to know the selectivity of these metal nitrates towards the ammonium carbonate and the order in which these metal nitrates will start reacting with the base. I know the Ksp of barium and aluminium nitrate but not of the ferric nitrate. Is there any way of knowing the order in which these compounds will react? 
How do I proceed with the analysis? Any link to a book or any article will be appreciated.

Comment: In other words, you are asking for the solubility products for the carbonates and hydrocarbonates of all the metals (91) out there, aren't you? If so, the question seems quite broad.

Comment: I have Ferric nitrate, barium nitrate and aluminium nitrate reacting with ammonium bicarbonate. I know the Ksp of barium and aluminium nitrate but not of the ferric nitrate. Is there any way of knowing the order in which these compounds will react?

Comment: It may be better to update the question, instead of keeping it as a comment appendix.

Answer (score 0):

When dissolving for exemple baryum nitrate in water, there is no baryum  nitrate any more in the solution. The solution is a mixture of Baryum ions and of independent Nitrate ions. So there is no "selectivity of these nitrates" as you say. Your question has no meaning. The only order of reaction is the order of the solubility products of the corresponding carbonates or bicarbonates of these metals. The trouble is that aluminium and ferric ions do not make any carbonates or bicarbonates. These compounds are decomposed into hydroxides. So basically, the answer of your question depends strongly on the pH of the solution.

Comment: My operating pH is between 7.5-8.